# usage of repetition in certain context

Tags: speech

I have a problem with my landline phone connection. So I have been registering complaints and the customer support team would come and fix the problem and every time they leave the same problem comes back and I am unable to make any call and again I register the complaint and again the problem is not resolved and the cycle continues.

I have been trying to put or explain the same thing in spoken English but I find it difficult.
for example. I tried - they will come, fix the problem, and again its malfunctions,they will come again, fix the problem, and again its malfunctions, and it goes on like this - so is there any way to avoid this repetition of the same sentence and convey the cyclical nature of the issue in natural English.

Comment: You could tell them that the problem **recurs** every time the technicians go away having fixed it. The definition and normal use  of the word **recur** includes the idea that the phenomenon occurs more than once so you don't need repetition. You could also start by saying you have a **recurrent** fault then explain that the fault **recurs** after the technicians leave having fixed it.

Comment: yes, I never thought of the word recur or recurrence.

Comment: I've converted my comment into an answer, Arun. Would you like ot accept it?

Comment: yes, I do accept it as an answer

Comment: There is a grey tick on your view of the answer. If you click on that you will accept the answer. If you don't accept an answer in that way the question will come up for review much later.

Comment: I have marked it as you mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tell them that the problem [recurs](https://www.lexico.com/definition/recur) every time the technicians go away having fixed it.

Lexico defines **recur** as

> Occur again periodically or repeatedly.

With the example

> ‘when the symptoms recurred, the doctor diagnosed something different’

The definition and normal use of the word recur includes the idea that the phenomenon occurs more than once so you don't need repetition. You could also start by saying you have a recurrent fault then explain that the fault recurs after the technicians leave having fixed it